# Installing FlinkML DenseVector dependency - why are there two different implementations?

Tags: apache-flink, flinkml

I'm a bit confused as to how to install the dependencies I actually need.

I'm new to both Java and Flink, and I think I'm missing something minor here. I'm doing a basic exercise where I need the `DenseVector` class, that supports basic mathematical operations.

I searched for `flink` docs and found [this class](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/api/java/org/apache/flink/ml/common/linalg/DenseVector.html). So it's artefact id is `org.apache.flink.ml.common.linalg.DenseVector`. This class supports operations such as dot product.

Now I go to the `flinkml` [tutorial page](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-ml-docs-release-2.1/docs/try-flink-ml/build-your-own-project/) and it says I need the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-ml-uber</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I install that however, the only `DenseVector` I get installed is [this one](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-ml-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/ml/linalg/DenseVector.html), which seems to be representing the same entity, but the API is very limited - it basically supports no mathematical operations.

My question is: I can't seem to find a way to install a dependency that would give me access to `org.apache.flink.ml.common.linalg.DenseVector`. What maven dependency do I need to get that? I've checked a few packages at https://mvnrepository.com/, but could not find the one I need. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different implementations because there was a major refactor with FlinkML 2.0.

You can install the dependency according to https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-ml-docs-release-2.1/docs/try-flink-ml/build-your-own-project/. Then you can get access to those mathematical operations by using this class https://github.com/apache/flink-ml/blob/master/flink-ml-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/ml/linalg/BLAS.java .

Maybe we can use the answer provided by the owner and close this thread.

Comment: I will use your answer because it tells how to stay on the latest version and where to find the refactored APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out what was going on. Apparently, there was a major refactor with FlinkML 2.0, because the package I'm interested in is available all the way up to this version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-ml-lib_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.7</version>
</dependency>
```

With this version, the latest update that is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-ml-lib_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

the codebase was refactored as the dependency I was looking for can now be find with this import:
`import org.apache.flink.ml.math.DenseVector;`
This vector implementation has all mathematical operations I was interested in.